# php preg_match extract args

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Does anyone know how to get the int from this preg_match? It's only showing me the URI.

```
$uri = "/user/view/2";
$pattern = "/user/view/[0-9]+";

if(preg_match('#^' . $pattern . '$#', $uri, $matched)) {
    print_r($matched);
}
else {
    echo "No match!";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no capture group in your pattern. Change:

```
$pattern = "/user/view/[0-9]+";
```

To:

```
$pattern = "/user/view/([0-9]+)";
```

And it will be in `$matched[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [T-Regx](https://github.com/Danon/T-Regx) and go

```
 pattern('^/user/view/[0-9]+$')->match($uri)
     ->forFirst(function (Match $match) {
         $int = $match->group(1);
         print_r($int);
     })
     ->orReturn("No match!");
```

And you don't have to delimiter it with `#`!